getting error in github workflow: remote: duplicate header : "Authorisation"
I'm using self hosted runner in my workflow. For some reason, getting the following error in the checkout step
error:
Fetching the repository
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --unshallow origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
  remote: Duplicate header: "Authorization"
  Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/og/snow/': The requested URL returned error: 400
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128


workflow code:
 determine_scope:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    outputs:
      prev_sha: ${{ steps.prev_sha_fetch.outputs.prev_sha }}
      deploy: ${{ steps.scope_check.outputs.deploy }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Fetch all commit history
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Fetch Prev SHA
        id: prev_sha_fetch
        run: |
          prev_sha=$(curl -L -s \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/workflows/${{ inputs.workflow_name }}/runs?branch=main&status=success&per_page=1" \
            | jq -r '.workflow_runs[0].head_sha'
          )
          echo "Current SHA: ${{ github.sha }}"
          echo "Previous SHA: $prev_sha"
          
          if [[ "$prev_sha" != "null" && -n "$prev_sha" ]]; then
            echo "::notice ::Triggered partial deployment"
          else
            echo "::notice ::Triggered full deployment"
            prev_sha='null'
          fi
          
          echo "prev_sha=$prev_sha" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT


tried different checkout versions, also used persist-credentials: false, nothing worked.

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/1830. This SO thread also seems to be a duplicate.

Your repo or your self-hosted runner (if you are using one) must have a git configuration file that sets git credentials in addition to GitHub workflow setting GITHUB_TOKEN in the auth header.
You may be able to see under Checkout step of your workflow a reference to .gitconfig or .gitcredentials
